# jquery - what is the best way for selector to select element with name 'x';

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to select elements in jQuery ie. `$('#id')` with their name attribute?

Comment: id cant repeat in dom. SO why you need to add name along side? #id should be best way

Comment: @mithunsatheesh OP is not asking that, check the title of the question.

Comment: see one of the answers below. its description is confusing people.

Comment: `$('[name="name"]')` is what you would use; it may return more than one element, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get elements with name attribute as shown below :

```
$('input[name="myname"]')
```

OR

```
$('.className[name="myname"]')
```

OR

```
$('[name="myname"]')   //this will return object(because there can be one or more elements with specified name in DOM)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s4nnpxLa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this : use **[jQuery Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** to select element by name

```
$('#id[name="nameOfElement"]')
```

You can use other jquery selectors with attribute selector like

with class `$('.className[name="nameOfElement"]')`

with tag type `$('input[name="nameOfElement"]')`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5d4nx4dc/4/)**

Comment: This almost never makes sense, because `#id` is already identifying.

Comment: id cant repeat in dom. SO why you need to add name along side?

Comment: What if I don't have id? Could I use class of the element? `$('.class[name="nameOfElement"]')`

Comment: id should always be unique, adding the name attribute does nothing

Comment: what if OP wants to do some operation for id (which is unique) with name=nameOfElement otherwise don't do anything

Comment: If you don't have id then you can use class or element tag with attribute selector. like for input fields `$('input[name="nameOfInput"]')`

Answer (score 0):

you can get select element as shown below.

```
$('select[name="x"]')
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks..